# Finding all pairs of amicable numbers from 2 to an upper range - incorrect output

Tags: c, function, output

I am trying to write a function which finds all pairs of amicable numbers from 2 to a given upper range.

I wrote a function that finds the sum of divisors of a given number.

I also wrote a function that uses the fact that if sum of devisors of **num1** is **S(num1)**,  and **num2=s(num1)-num1**  has the same sum of devisors, then num1 and num2 are amicable numbers.

Here is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void amicableNumbers(int n);
int findSumOfDevisors(int num);

void main() {
    int upperRange;

    printf("enter the value for upper range: ");
    scanf("%d", &upperRange);
    printf("the amicable numbers between 2 and %d:\n", upperRange);
    amicableNumbers(upperRange);
}

void amicableNumbers(int n) {
    int sum, sum2, i;

    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        sum = findSumOfDevisors(i);
        if (sum > i && sum <= n) {
            sum2 = findSumOfDevisors(sum);
            if (sum2 == i)
                printf("%d and %d \n", i, sum);
        }
    }
}

int findSumOfDevisors(int num) {
    int sum = 1, i, n;
    
    n = (int)sqrt((double)num);
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        if ((n % i) == 0) {
            sum += i;
            sum += n / i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

However, when I run this I get the wrong output. For instance, for the upperRange `301`, I get that there are not any amicable numbers in the range `2-301`.

> *Amicable numbers* are two different numbers so related that the sum of the proper divisors of each is equal to the other number. For instance, the pair 220 and 284 are amicable numbers. The sum of the proper divisors of 220 is 1+2+4+5+10+11+20+22+44+55+110=284 and the sum of the proper divisors of 284 is 1+2+4+71+142=220.
>
> A *proper divisor* to a number is a positive factor to that number except the number itself.

Comment: @chux yes, it is right sir. He has problem with findSumOfDevisors

Comment: `n =(int) sqrt((double)num);` may not provide the integer square root desired given slight inaccurateracies possible with `sqrt()`.  Suggest only using integer math: `for (i = 2; i <= num/i; i++)`

Comment: `findSumOfDivisors`  *

Comment: OT:  regardless of what visual studio will let the programmer get away with, the return type from `main()` is always `int`

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 3):

OP's `findSumOfDevisors()` has troubles.  Perhaps other code does too.

1. `sqrt()` is not obliged to give an *exactly* correct square root - some weaker implementations may result in a value just above or just below the expected answer.  Coupled with the `(int)` which truncates the fraction, an answer like 123.999999999... becomes 123 instead of 124.  In any case, floating point math with its precision issues is not needed here.

   Suggest only using integer math:

   ```
   // n =(int) sqrt((double)num);
   // for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
   for (i = 2; i <= num/i; i++)
   ```
2. Avoid overflow.

   ```
   // for (i = 2; i*i <= num; i++)  `i*i` may overflow.
   for (i = 2; i <= num/i; i++)
   ```
3. Summing the same value twice?  When the divisor and quotient are the same, code counts them both.  I'd expect only one.

   ```
   sum += i;
   // sum += n / i;
   if (i != n/i) sum += n/i;
   ```
4. For completeness, I'd expect `findSumOfDevisors(0)`, `findSumOfDevisors(1)` to return 0 and not 1 like OP's code.  Negative numbers are another issue  not addressed.

   ```
   // int sum = 1;
   int sum = num > 1;
   ```
5. Using expensive `/, %` or getting 2-for-1?  Consider the following code. The `%` and `/` each invoke potentially some an expensive remainder and division calculation.   Yet with many good compilers, the `num/i` and `num % i` will cause emitted code to calculate both of those in one operation.   Best to code for clarity, yet if permanence is a concern, investigate the result of a good optimizing compiler.

   ```
   for (i = 2; i < num/i; i++) {
     if (num%i == 0) {
   ```

Answer (score 2):

It is not advisable to use floating point arithmetic in `findSumOfDivisors`, try this instead:

```
int findSumOfDivisors(int num) {
    int sum = 1, div, i;

    for (i = 2; i <= (div = num / i); i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            sum += i;
            if (i == div)
                break;
            sum += div;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Furthermore, your `amicableNumbers` function is too complicated, you should simply test if the sum of divisors of the sum is the original number:

```
void amicableNumbers(int n) {
    int sum, i;

    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        sum = findSumOfDivisors(i);
        if (sum > i && sum <= n && findSumOfDivisors(sum) == i)
            printf("%d and %d\n", i, sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the prototype for `main` without arguments is `int main(void)` and you should test the return value of `scanf()` and return `0` from `main`.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int findSumOfDivisors(int num) {
    int sum = 1, div, i;

    for (i = 2; i <= (div = num / i); i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            sum += i;
            if (i == div)
                break;
            sum += div;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

void amicableNumbers(int n) {
    int sum, i;

    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        sum = findSumOfDivisors(i);
        if (sum > i && sum <= n && findSumOfDivisors(sum) == i)
            printf("%d and %d\n", i, sum);
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int upperRange;

    printf("enter the value for upper range: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &upperRange) == 1) {
        printf("the amicable numbers between 2 and %d:\n", upperRange);
        amicableNumbers(upperRange);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's my first way, however it may overflow as @chux has noted. Anyway, +1 for sharing my idea.

Comment: Additionally, as I mention in my answer, **`if (sum > i && sum <= n)` can be simplified as `i < sum`**, so `if(i < sum && findSumOfDivisors(sum) == i)` is better

Comment: yes, it **may**, if we have chance to overcome the issue having minute possibility, why do we give it a hard time?

Comment: @snr: the test `sum <= n` ensures you only produce pairs of amicable numbers with both elements between `2` and `n`.

Comment: @snr: corrected the potential overflow on `i * i < n`

Answer (score 1):

Your `findSumOfDevisors` function is wrong. Besides, IMO `sqrt()` function is overwhelming for performance. Instead, you should use `i <= num / 2`

```
int findSumOfDevisors(int num)
{
    int sum = 1, i,n;

    //n =(int) sqrt((double)num);
    for (i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++)
    {
        if ((num % i) == 0)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Moreover, `if (sum > i && sum <= n)` can be simplified as `i < sum`

Comment: @snr, why is my sqrt function overwhelming? how should it be fixed instead of using i*i <= n? I dont get it.

Comment: With `findSumOfDevisors(9)` this code looks like it is trying to sum `1+3+3+9`.  I'd expect `1+3+9`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this function

```
int findSumOfDevisors(int num)
```

It's a typing mistake you wanted to put num not n
the correct function is

```
int findSumOfDevisors(int num)
{
int sum = 1, i,n;

 n =(int) sqrt((double)num);
for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    if ((num % i) == 0)
    {
        sum += i;

        // If divisors are equal, add only one 
        if (num /i != i)
        {
            sum += num / i;
        } 
    }
}
return sum;
}
```

Comment: There is another bug in this function: the square root of perfect squares should be counted only once.

Comment: @chqrlie You are right.